# More than one object of type class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a bean configuration for handling dates in object-to-json transformer like below

```
 <spring:beans>
     <spring:bean id="jacksonObjectMapper"     class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
      <spring:bean
           class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        <spring:property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
        <spring:property name="arguments">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS</spring:value>
                <spring:value>false</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

I am getting the error

More than one object of type class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper registered but only one expected.

How can i fix this error?

Comment: What is your input payload ? put your full config with input payload

Comment: hmm... just noticed myself, that it is not as easy as i thought to do what i suggested in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your 2nd bean definition does not have any Id or name defined. But it has a reference to  the first bean ref="jacksonObjectMapper".

Answer (score -1):

You may have an extra org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper declared in you xml. Can you check it out?